# Ellipse or hyperbola?

Tags: analytic-geometry

$C$ is the equation $$-2x^2+6xy+6y^2 = 1.$$

How can you see whether it is an ellipse or a hyperbola?

I've calculated the eigenvalues and eigenvectors but I don't know how to continue.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this getting close votes and downvotes? The user wants to see if a quadratic form is an ellipse or a hyperbola and has demonstrated work in this direction. The question has a concrete answer in terms of the determinant of the matrix of the form, which can be computed in terms of the eigenvalues (the work the user has already done).

Comment: @hunter "...has demonstrated work...". really? and where is this work? OP doesn't understand what is ellipse/hyperbola or what is quadratic form and eigenvalues, and I can't help with it.

Comment: @MichaelGaluza: Do you expect the OP to type all his computations leading to the eigenvalues? Come on! He is supposed to show *some context*, not necessarily his own work (as discussed in [this thread on Meta MSE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21109/why-does-the-criteria-for-a-good-question-change-with-reputation)), in order for us to evaluate his knowledge of the subject and know how to answer. Since the OP claims he has already computed the eigenvalues, this clearly shows at least a basic understanding of the issue. He just doesn't know what to do with those eigenvalues.

Comment: @AlexM. It's really bad way (IMHO, of course). I see it so: "Folks, $C$ is <something>. How can I determine <something trivial/obvious/very basic>. I've calculated <something related to this> (actually no, I googled and there are some words from first page), but I don't know how to continue." There is no sense in close votes in such case: write something like "My attempt: need help" and good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the eigenvalues have the same sign, you'll get an ellipse. If they're opposite sign, you'll get a hyperbola. You may find this article helpful.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections